# How to set up SBT to compile .proto files?

Tags: java, protocol-buffers, sbt

So far I found only one SBT project which uses Protocol Buffers. http://google.com/codesearch#search/&q=protobuf+file:build.sbt&type=cs
but... its author runs protobuf compiler manually.

Is it possible to automate .proto -> .java compilation with SBT ?

Answer (score 1):

There's an sbt plugin for compiling protocol buffer files - https://github.com/sbt/sbt-protobuf